# Install Ganache UI on Windows 8.1

Tags: solidity, truffle, windows

I am trying to install Ganache on my windows 8.1 machine.

I downloaded the `Ganache.appx` from the [official Ganach website](http://truffleframework.com/ganache/).

I furthermore installed the [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).

As pointed out in the [documentation](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache):

> Before building, create the ./certs directory with the following
>   files:
>
> ./certs/cert.pfx

Which I created together in a folder:

[image]

However, now I am stuck how to install ganache. Any suggestions for the next steps?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1):

**Current Behavior**

When I install testrpc by installing instruction for windows, the error appears " The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found." I think the most person will not install this for windows PC.

1. Version used: Newest?
2. Environment name and version (e.g. PHP 5.4 on
   nginx 1.9.1):
3. Windows 10 64 Server type and version:

   Windows 10 64 Operating System and version:

   Windows 10 64 NodeJs Version:
   Node 6.7.0

TestRPC is easy to install on Windows. Just download and install [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/), then run the following command:

```
$ npm install 
$ npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't download the `*.appx`. That's the windows 10 store app format. Run the following code in your cmd

```
git clone git@github.com:/trufflesuite/ganache
cd ganache
npm install -g windows-build-tools
npm install
npm start
```

Note: The ganache team has previously expressed they are currently not interested in expanding official support to lower windows versions. By following the above steps you are attempting to build yourself. The steps mentioned in their readme are only for Windows 10 at the time of writing.

Answer based off https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/issues/337